# Powerbuilder 2017 client application producting the following error - ADO.NET is not supported in your current installation

Tags: database, ado.net, powerbuilder

I have installed the PowerBuilder Runtime Packager and still get the ADO.NET not supported error.

I have installed the 32 and 64 bit files.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you copy the following files to the folder where the EXE resides and try again and see if it works.

> appeon\Shared\PowerBuilder\PBRTH170.dll
>   appeon\Shared\PowerBuilder\atl100.dll
>   appeon\Shared\PowerBuilder\msvcr100.dll
>   appeon\Shared\PowerBuilder\msvcp100.dll
>   appeon\Shared\PowerBuilder\pbado170.dll
>   appeon\Shared\PowerBuilder\pbrth170.dll
>   appeon\PowerBuilder 17.0\DotNET\bin\sybase.PowerBuilder.Db.dll
>   appeon\PowerBuilder 17.0\DotNET\bin\sybase.PowerBuilder.DbExt.dll
>   appeon\PowerBuilder 17.0\DotNET\bin\Sybase.PowerBuilder.DataSource.Sharing.dll

Answer (score -1):

I try and it works in PowerBuilder2019

appeon\Shared\PowerBuilder\atl100.dll appeon\Shared\PowerBuilder\msvcr100.dll appeon\Shared\PowerBuilder\msvcp100.dll appeon\Shared\PowerBuilder\pbado170.dll appeon\Shared\PowerBuilder\pbrth170.dll appeon\PowerBuilder 19.0\DotNET\bin\sybase.PowerBuilder.Db.dll appeon\PowerBuilder 19.0\DotNET\bin\sybase.PowerBuilder.DbExt.dll appeon\PowerBuilder 19.0\DotNET\bin\Sybase.PowerBuilder.DataSource.Sharing.dll